# Equivalent Component For ButtonBar in Flex

Tags: apache-flex, flex3

I am having issue with ButtonBar as we can define only 3 styles for the buttons , but my requirement is to have as many buttons as we want with different style names .

Is there any component equivalent to  ButtonBar we can consider or is there any hack to achieve this .

Answer (score 0):

I used MenuBar component for the similar need.

you can see this link for example

http://blog.flexexamples.com/category/halo/menubar/